# Building libcsv problems

Tags: c++, build

I'm having some trouble building the csv library libcsv.

I'm using Windows XP, MinGW compiler and MSYS command shell.

It configures ok (./configure) but when I go to build it I get the below error.  I realise it has to do with autoconf (it requires 2.65 or above) So what do I do here.  Do I download autoconf and have it in a separate directory marked c:\autoconf and have an environmental variable pointing to it?  Or,, does it go in the MSYS folder.

I have downloaded the binaries for autoconf and I just get a bunch of files.  The binary files are in a SHARE folder and a 'bin' folder. Do I put their contents into the MsYS share and bin folders?  Looking around the web I'm also seeing references to putting the autoconf binaries into my MinGW/bin folder.  I'm really not sure what to do here?

Can anyone help?   Thank you.

```
xxxx@XXXX-2FEF09FD39 ~
$ cd C:\libcsv-3.0.3

xxxx@XXXX-2FEF09FD39 /c/libcsv-3.0.3
$ make
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /c/libcsv-3.0.3/missing --run autoconf
/bin/m4: unrecognized option `--gnu'
Try `/bin/m4 --help' for more information.
autom4te: /bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
make: *** [configure] Error 1

xxxx@XXXX-2FEF09FD39 /c/libcsv-3.0.3
$
```